# how to pass string parameter in onclick function

Tags: javascript, jsp

Here is my jsp code

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function updatestatus(str){
    //window.location.href="updatestatus.jsp?cid="+str;
    alert(str);
}
function deletecompany(str1){
    alert(str1)
    //window.location.href="deletecompany.jsp?cid="+str1;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<%
String status=request.getParameter("status");
//String id=request.getParameter("id");
String id="0005";
out.println(id);
if(status.equals("approve")){
    out.println("<input type='button' value='update' onclick='updatestatus(\""+id+"\")'/>");
}else if(status.equals("reject")){
    out.println("<input type='button' value='delete' onclick='deletecompany(id)'/>");
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

I can get two types of button, but there is no response when I click. I have tried many parameter formats within the function bracket, they all don't work...I wonder what is the problem, would you give me some advice?

Thank you for your attention
best regards ;

Comment: plz check the html code after page loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code snippet:

```
<%
String status = request.getParameter("status");
String id     = request.getParameter("id");
String value  = null;
String func   = null;

if (status.equals("approve")) {
  value = "update";
  func  = "updatestatus";
} else if (status.equals("reject")) {
  value = "delete";
  func  = "deletecompany";
}
%>
 <input type='button' value='<%=value%>' onclick='<%=func%>("<%=id%>")'/>
```

**PS** Use JSTL instead of jsp scriptlets.

Comment: thank you very much,i found it will work if i put function inside onclick(),and i try    if(status.equals("approve")){
    out.println("<input type='button' value='update' onclick='window.location.href="updatestatus.jsp?cid="+id'>");}

Comment: however it doesn't work, i wonder what is the format problem inside onclick function . thank you for your kindly help!